# How do I install and launch jjazzlab on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I just picked up a piece of software called jjazzlab. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.  I can start the software from a terminal window and it runs with no issues, but it never seems to install.  What I'm hoping is that there is some way to get it to install so that I can find it with the show applications.

Does this application need to be started from a terminal window or is there another way to launch the software?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for installing Jazzlab from https://github.com/jjazzboss/JJazzLab-X? If so I will provide you with a link to the question at Ask Ubuntu that asks how to start a GUI application like Jazzlab by clicking its icon in Show Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're supposed to do exactly as you've been doing, from a command line.

According to the Linux installation [instructions](https://jjazzlab.gitbook.io/user-guide/installation) just do:

> Unzip the package.
>
> Start JJazzLab using bin/jjazzlab in the installation directory.

This instructions are generic and applicable to any Linux distro.
They mention an alternative installation by native package but that is only available for ArchLinux and Manjaro Linux (presumably also any other Arcg derivative). So, for Ubuntu, you need to run it in the command line.

Comment: Those instructions are exactly what my comment that I posted before you posted your answer linked to, but I went further and not only suggested making a desktop shortcut to Jazzlab but also mentioned that this is already a frequently asked question at Ask Ubuntu and therefore this question is possibly a duplicate of that frequently asked question.

Comment: @karel Yes, this is what I found in a cursory search. If there's a duplicate please report as such

Comment: The duplicate question link that I would suggest if it applies to this question is [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/).